# show transparent background when function used?

Tags: jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    var overlayObject = $("a[rel]").overlay({ 
        top: 50,
        expose: {
                    color: '#232323',
                    closeOnClick: true
                },

                onClose:function() {   
                    $('#reg-login').hide();
                    $('#reg-register').hide();
                },
        effect: 'apple'
 });
```

hi, how can I not show the black background which comes up in this function. I just dont want to show anything in the background, just a normal webpage behind, how can i do that?

If i delete color: '#232323', then some blue background comes up.

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `expose` method provided by the overlay. This brings focus to the element and slowly fades everything else around it. If you do not want the 'mask overlay', simply remove the expose effect, and find the css element `#mask` and give it a background:transparent. Alternatively, you could use the `mask:{}` parameter and pass to it a transparent gif (or png) which will give the same effect.

Comment: First of all, sorry for late reply, as i was travelling. Thanks so much, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Secondly, i want to ask, since i am using var overlayObject = $("a[rel]").overlay, now i cant use rel="nofollow" to any of my a href tag. Is there a way, i can achieve this?

Comment: @sammry change [rel] to a different parameter that the element accepts. You could use 'title', it is very common, and then `$('a[title]').overlay`

Comment: thanks but am already using the title attribute for others, where can i get the list of acceptable elements, i have already used for image, title, rel, as of now, will google it meantime. Thanks again